# $\int_0^1 g(x) \ dx = \int_{|w|=1} g(w)\log(w) \ dw$

Tags: complex-analysis

$$\int_0^1 g(x) \ dx = \int_{|w|=1} g(w)\log(w) \ dw$$, where $g(x)$ is a holomorphic function on the closed disc centered at the origin of radius 1.

A hint suggests to use $\log w = \log |w| + i \arg (w)$ where $\arg (w) \in [0,2\pi)$. Following the hint I used a keyhole contour with the "corridor" along real axis, with a small circle of radius epsilon in the centre, and a large circle of radius 1 on the outside tranversed anticlockwise.

I'm unable to proceed with the integral, and I manage to get $\int_{|w| = \epsilon} g(w) \log(w) \ dw + \int_{|w| =1} g(w) \log(w) \ dw = 0$, but im unsure how to get the limits to be from 0 to 1

Comment: I think you are on the right track, the only thing left is to show that the integral around the circle with radius $\epsilon$ vanishs in the limit of zero radius. This can be achieved by taylor expanding around the origin, which is legal because $g$ is holomorphic inside at $0$.

Comment: @tired but then all that would show is that $\int_{|w|=1} g(w) \log(w) \ dw = 0$, that doesnt show it equals the required real integral.

Comment: what are the contribiutions from the corridor?
i furthermore suspect, that a factor of $2\pi i$ is missing somewhere.

Comment: @tired they would surely cancel out, because we traverse the keyhole anticlockwise, which would give one corridor being traversed clockwise and the other anticlockwise. We then take the limit to "close" the corridor and end up with them vanishing.

Comment: no, because of the discontinuity of $\log(z)$ at the critical line $(0,1)$.

Comment: @tired then I'm not sure about how we would do it - I mean, by your argument surely we cannot integrate $g(w)\log(w)$ in the circle of radius 1 as the +ve real axis is the branch taken out here?

Comment: @tired oh i see! thanks

Comment: see my answer below...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, let's see:

Because $g$ has no poles inside the unit disc, we can write by Cauchy's integral formula 
$$
\int_{|z|=1,\arg(z)\in(0+\epsilon,2\pi-\epsilon)}g(z)\log(z)+\int_{|\epsilon|,\arg(\epsilon)\in(\pi/2,3\pi/2) }g(z)\log(z)+\int_{i\epsilon}^{i\epsilon+1}g(x)\log(x)+\int_{-i\epsilon+1}^{-i\epsilon}g(x)\log(x)=0
$$

where the limit $\epsilon\rightarrow0$ is implicit.

As already mentionend in my comment the small semi circle will vansih as the integrand goes as $\mathcal{O}( \epsilon\log(\epsilon)g(\epsilon))$ as $\epsilon\rightarrow0$. Using the definition of logarithm you gave, we further simplify:

$$
\int_{|z|=1}g(z)\log(z)+\int_{0}^{1}g(x)\log(x+i\epsilon)-\int_{0}^{1}g(x)\log(x-i\epsilon)=0
$$

Writing $\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0}log(x\pm i\epsilon)=\log(|x|)+i\arg(\pm \epsilon/x)=\log(|x|)+i 2\pi \Theta(-\epsilon)$ we get
$$
\int_{|z|=1}g(z)\log(z)=2 \pi i\int_{0}^{1}g(x)
$$

Comment: Why is it discontinous on the line segment, but not on the circle |z| = 1? I mean, we have excluded the real axis for the lgoarithm, so it is not continuous there at z = 1

Comment: similary, for the circle we take epsilon to be 0, that leads to $\log 0 $ which is undefined.

Comment: it is not really continuous, i have implicitly taken out a small region around the real line. The last equation shows that the integrand is indeed discontinuous at the real line. Otherwise we would have $0$

Comment: yes, but $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}(x \log (x))=0$

Comment: clear now?
I also wondering, were the $2 \pi$ is gone.

Comment: Indeed - very clear.